# How to test to make sure a function get called?

Tags: unit-testing, go, gorilla

I want to do unit test. Just to make it simple, I just want to make sure that the "JWTCheck" get called. How do I do that?

This is the file where I implement the JWTCheck:

```
type JWTChecker struct {
    SubjectPrefix string   
}

func (j *JWTChecker) JWTCheck(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    // Do something
}
```

And this is where I implement the router:

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"

    )

// Router returns a preconfigured router for application
func (a *Adapter) Router() http.Handler {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    jwtChecker := JWTChecker{
        SubjectPrefix: "myappName",
    }

    /* Setup Loans Routes */
    loanrouter := router.PathPrefix("/lending/loans").Subrouter()
    if !a.Debug {
        loanrouter.Use(jwtChecker.JWTCheck)
    }
    loanrouter.HandleFunc("/customer/{customerid}/loan/{loanid}", a.GetLoan).Methods("GET")

    return router
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `net/http/httptest` to write unit test case and the function name of the test cases would `Test` as prefix to the function name you wants to test. Also the filename will start with `yourfilename_test.go`

```
func Test<YourFuncName>(t *testing.T) {

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "<your function url>", nil)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    handler.ServeHTTP(w, req)

    if w.Code != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("Request failed, got: %d, expected: %d.", w.Code, http.StatusOK)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't *have to*, but that's the workflow for the built-in unit test suite and the stdlib method for testing http handlers. That doesn't mean there's no other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow @saddam advice to write your test code.

Then use coverage support in `go test` to run the test and verify that `JWTCheck` is covered.

```
go test -coverprofile=.coverage.out && go tool cover -html=.coverage.out
```